# Bulma fullheight layout with scrollable area in middle

Tags: css, bulma

I want to create a fullheight layout with a top navigation bar, middle area and footer. The Top Navigation and Footer should always stay at the top and bottom, respectively. The layout I managed to create looks somewhat like this:

[image: Dashboard Layout]

I implemented this with:

```
<section class="hero is-fullheight">
        <div class="hero-head">
            <the-navbar></the-navbar>
        </div>
        <div class="hero-body">
            <div class="container">
                <dashboard/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="hero-foot">
            <tab-navigation></tab-navigation>
        </div>
</section>
```

The problem now is that when I have other elements than the `<dashboard/>` in the hero-body (like a long list of boxes) the fullheight layout is lost, making the site longer than the display height. How can I make the hero-body div scrollable? I tried adding `overflow: auto;` but that doesn't work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apply `height` or `max-height` for `hero-body` and then apply `overflow: auto;`. May be you can hide overflow-x(`overflow-x:hidden`) and apply scroll only vertically by `overflow-y:auto`.